# Cannot use Python 3.10 as interpreter on Pycharm

Tags: 18.04, python, pycharm

I have `python3.10` installed but I cannot set it as an interpreter.

The installation can be confirmed by calling `python3.10` directly on the terminal, and with the command below:

```
$ ls -ls /usr/bin/python*
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Apr 16  2018 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Apr 16  2018 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7
3548 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3633000 Feb 27  2021 /usr/bin/python2.7
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Nov 17 05:41 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.6
5312 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5437464 Oct  5 07:05 /usr/bin/python3.10
4424 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4526456 Jan 26  2021 /usr/bin/python3.6
4424 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4526456 Jan 26  2021 /usr/bin/python3.6m
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      10 Nov 17 05:41 /usr/bin/python3m -> python3.6m
```

However, when trying to configure `python3.10` as the venv on Pycharm using the path above, I get `Failed to create virtual environment`. I think it has something to do with the arrows in the terminal print out above, so if anyone could help explain and configure it properly, it would be really helpful.

Also, just to clarify, I want to make a virtual interpreter for this project only, and not use the system interpreter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Need to install the `venv` lib for each version of python:

In this case,

```
sudo apt-get install python3.10-venv
```

Comment: this didn't work for me - I already have this installed

Comment: @LostCrotchet any details? what does it say?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add 3.10 to 'Existing environment' first. If you try 'New environment' it can't be added.[image]