# How to get Python interpreter to work on PyCharm?

Tags: python3, pycharm

How do you get Python interpreter to work on PyCharm? I have Python 3.10 installed on Ubuntu 22.

Comment: Have you [read the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html)? If so; at what step is there a problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu Core 22? That is the only version of Ubuntu to use a single digit version number. If not please edit the question and put in the actual full version info.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot use Python 3.10 as interpreter on Pycharm](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1376798/cannot-use-python-3-10-as-interpreter-on-pycharm)